# SQL UPDATE ignores WHERE

Tags: mysql

I need a bit of help here...

I'm trying to UPDATE a table which is connected to another table like the next ones:

```
             table1
 ID_Website |  descr  |  level

    100                 2
    104                 2
    105                 3
```

And the other table:

```
     table2

 ID   |       URL

 100     www.google.es
 104     www.youtube.es
 105     stackoverflow.com
```

I tried to write something on "descr" column with

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2
SET descr = 'something'
WHERE table1.level = '2'
AND table2.URL = 'www.google.es'
```

But, what it makes, is:

```
             table1
 ID_Website |  descr  |  level

    100      something    2
    104      something    2
    105                   3
```

I know that the problem is in that "JOIN", because it makes no sense. But i tried to write "FROM" like i read in other posts and it returns a syntax error. 
Both tables where joinned directly when we created the tables and now sql doesn't let us to "INNER JOIN" them (when we use a SELECT, there's no need to do INNER JOINs).

I have no idea how to proceed...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `ON` clause in the `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.ID_Website = table2.ID
--          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SET descr = 'something'
WHERE table1.level = '2'
AND table2.URL = 'www.google.es'
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5761d/1)]

Comment: Okay, that was the answer and now it works! Thanks!!